# Send information from the WCF to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, wcf, service

To call the `WCF` service from `JavaScript`, using - AJAX: **[Calling WCF Services using jQuery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery)**

**My question is:**

Is there a way after one request to keep something related to `JavaScript`,

and then send information from the `WCF` **without** receiving requests from the JS?

(If there is some neat information on the subject, I'd be happy to receive it.)

Comment: do you want that WCF keeps sending you messages without receiving requests? If this is what you mean than you should try using http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-websockets-20091029/

Comment: @EhsanUllah. Yes, this is my intention.

Comment: have you read the link i mentioned? Because that is the solution in your scenario

Comment: @EhsanUllah. I read, but the use of WebSocket in Wcf enabled only in .NET 4.5 and I use 4, there are other ways?

Comment: @HodayaShalom: It could be important to know which web browser and in which version you use. WebSocket could be your choice only if the web browser implemented it (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websocket#Browser_implementation)). [ASP.NET SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) could be an alternative, but it's important also which OS you use. For example you can't use WebSocket of SignalR on Windows 7 even if you install IE10 on the computer.

Comment: @Oleg. I can not accomplish this on wcf because I use .NET 4! There is no other way to do this? (I can implement the interface of [ICallbackEventHandler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/435591/Responsive-WCF-service-With-ICallbackEventHandler). Question is how to do it on the JS client).

Comment: @HodayaShalom: You wrote already about support of .NET 4. Could you write your other requirements to the client: supported operations systems and web browsers?

Comment: @Oleg. It should be used to PhoneGap (iOS and Android), I would prefer that it will also support all browsers, but mainly better in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SignalR` is a good way to do it,

you can see this in detail in the following question:

**[Use SignalR to notify from wcf to JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521043/use-signalr-to-notify-from-wcf-to-js)**

Comment: You should only understand that SignalR works as *permanent pooling* of the server from the clients side on the most old web browsers. Even in case of IE10 which supports WebSocket in general SignalR are able to use WebSocket only on Windows 8 and *not on Windows 7*. I recommend you to trace HTTP traffic using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome. So SignalR is a good design solution for new clients, but it's not real solution for Windows 7 clients.

Comment: What "works"? Are Long Pooling will be used or WebSockets? Do you examined the HTTP traffic? Could you see HTTP GET request like `http://localhost:port/signalr?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=...` which will be send from the client to the server **every second**?