# Use SignalR to notify from wcf to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wcf, signalr

I want to use `SignalR` to recognize `Jquery` client on `WCF service` and board him messages even without a request. (Ie after the first request the client sends to the service, the service can to know him and send him messages).

I do not know if this is the best way to do this, but it's all I could find. (Except WebSocket that are supported only in VS 2012).

I added in the `Global` file on the Service the following function:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
}
```

I created Chat.cs:

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        // Call the addMessage method on all clients
        Clients.All.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```

In the `JS` project I added the `JS` files of `SignalR`:

```
<script src="../JavaScript/jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Function that uses it:

```
function Chat() {

    $(function () {
        // Proxy created on the fly          
        var chat = $.connection.chat;

        // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it          
        chat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
            alert(message);
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            // Call the chat method on the server
            chat.server.send('aa');
        });
    });

}
```

This is something new to me so sorry if the question stupid, but how the SignalR of JS should know the Service, where I should define him? (This calls for a Cross-Domain)

(The variable `$.connection.chat` is Undefined)

I'm sure I missed a few things, especially the main thing that he **how to link the service and JS via SignalR**?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how WCF fits into the picture? All you show here is basic SignalR client/server communication. Also, make sure you check out the samples:  https://github.com/SignalR/Samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was missing is the use **SignalR with cross-domain**.

On Global file I changed the code:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration() { EnableCrossDomain = true });
}
```

It is important to note here that since I use cross-domain I have code in `Application_BeginRequest` function that  should cancel it when done `SignalR` request otherwise **it does not work**. So I canceled it this way:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Here is testing whether this request SignalR, if not I do the following code
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.IndexOf("signalr") == -1)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                {

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, x-requested-with");

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

                }
            }
        }
```

**On the client:**

I added the scripts of `SignalR` and `Jquery`, and I deleted this script:

`<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Because there's cross-domain calls it is **not needed.**

The connection is in the following function:

```
var connection;
var contosoChatHubProxy;

function RegisterToServiceMessege() {
    connection = $.hubConnection();
    connection.url = 'http://localhost:xxx/signalr';
    contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('ChatHub');
    //This part happens when function broadcastMessage is activated(from the server)
    contosoChatHubProxy.on('broadcastMessage', function (userName, message) {
        alert('You have a messege:\n' + userName + ' ' + message);
    });
    connection.start()
    .done(function () {
        console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);
    })
    .fail(function () { console.log('Could not connect'); });
}
```

Chat.cs on the server:

```
 [HubName("ChatHub")]
    public class Chat : Hub
    {
        [HubMethodName("Send")]
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

Call to a function `Send` from one of customers is as follows:

```
function SendMessege() {
    contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('Send', 'aaa', 'bbb').done(function () {
        console.log('Invocation of NewContosoChatMessage succeeded');
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.log('Invocation of NewContosoChatMessage failed. Error: ' + error);
    });

}
```

**All clients receive the sent message.**

(You can check this by running several browsers simultaneously.)

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.0 of SignalR you can no longer enable Cors using this code:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration() { EnableCrossDomain = true });
    }
```

Instead, you must add those two lines in your Startup class initializing method:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.MapSignalR();           
}
```

And, what may not be obvious for everyone, if you don't want to host SignalR using its self-hosting library, then remember to change your project to WebApplication. In my case I was trying to append Signalr to WCFProject. And runtime wouldn't even go to this Configuration method of Startup, thus causing constant errors forbidding access to signalr resources